# How to scroll a ScrollViewer with animation

Tags: windows-8, windows-store-apps, scrollviewer, windows-store

I have a scrollviewer in a windows store app, I want to scroll it to a specific location, `ScrollToHorizontalOffset` does that but without animation, I want to do that with animation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you do this in Windows 8.1, use ChangeView to use animations.

If you're stuck doing it in Windows 8, then you'll need [WinRTXamlToolkit](http://winrtxamltoolkit.codeplex.com). It adds an extension method: `ScrollToHorizontalOffsetWithAnimation`.